# Check if an std::filesystem::path is inside a directory

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

I have a root path represented by an `std::filesystem::path`. I want to add some user provided filename to this path and make sure the resulting path is not out of the root directory.

For example:

```cpp
    std::filesystem::path root = "/foo/bar";
    std::filesystem::path userFile = "ham/spam";
    std::filesystem::path finalPath = root / userFile;
```

The final path is ok, it is inside `/foo/bar`.
But if I give `../ham/spam` to the `userFile` variable, this will result in a file outside the define `rootPath`.

How can I check that the resulting file keeps inside its allowed boundaries ?

Comment: Does this help? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/canonical

Comment: If only the `std::filesystem` library contained some function that computed a new `absolute` path, wouldn't it be useful?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: No, it wouldn't, because `absolute` (and `canonical` for that matter) both require the path to *exist*. Which it may not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you need to [normalize the final path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/lexically_normal). This removes all `.` and `..`s in the path. Then, you need to check to see if it has any mismatches in its directory iterator range, relative to `root`. And there's a [standard library algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) for that.

So overall, the code looks like this:

```
std::optional<fs::path> MakeAbsolute(const fs::path &root, const fs::path &userPath)
{
    auto finalPath = (root / userPath).lexically_normal();

    auto[rootEnd, nothing] = std::mismatch(root.begin(), root.end(), finalPath.begin());

    if(rootEnd != root.end())
        return std::nullopt;

    return finalPath;
}
```

Note that this only works theoretically; the user may have used symlink shenanigans within the root directory to break out of your root directory. You would need to [use `canonical`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical) rather than `lexically_normal` to ensure that this doesn't happen. However, `canonical` *requires* that the path exist, so if this is a path to a file/directory that needs to be created, it won't work.

Comment: use `std::filesystem::weakly_canonical()` to avoid requirement of existance in `canonical`